# Can I capture simulator output to console in my testbench?

Tags: unit-testing, vhdl, simulator

I have a testbench to test my VHDL device (DUT), but part of the DUT debug output is an ASSERT/REPORT message to the console, which I would like to check for correctness but I can't change the DUT. The only way I can think of is to post-process the output log file.

Is there any way of capturing the console output in the testbench, so I can check the DUT output directly?

Comment: The output written to STDOUT and STDERR, so you can connect any other program to it with e.g. a pipe. You can also use predefined frameworks like [VUnit](https://github.com/VUnit/vunit), that handle all this for you.

Comment: This would usually be done as a post process task, not as part of the testbench. If you need to process the results, instead of generating asserts, have a method of checking the data in the testbench.

Comment: Can you describe your tool chain environment a bit? Who's simulator and are there any constraints on VHDL revision? Vunit came to mind also given your restriction of not modifying the DUT. Relying instead on a procedural level interface to generate callbacks and provide access to the design's information model. You might also describe what you'd use the 'correctness' of an assertion statement for in your testbench.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I already use Vunit, but this would be post-processing the log files in Python, which is the solution at the moment, but I was trying to find another.  If I didn't make it clear enough, the asserts are generated by the DUT, and cannot be changed.  I'm using Active-HDL, VHDL2008.

Comment: I don't know a solution for this but if you were allowed to change the original asserts and reports to those provided by VUnit you can also use VUnit's mocking support to check the output. In that way you avoid checking the log file which has a simulator specific format. See https://vunit.github.io/logging/user_guide.html for more info.

Comment: Another approach would be to use VUnit preprocessing support to replace the asserts and reports on the fly. When setting up the VUnit test environment for the VHDL working group I used this to remove some oddities in the IEEE standard libraries which prevented proper testing. The original and released code is not permanently modified, just temporarily when being tested. Not ideal but maybe an acceptable compromise.

Answer (score 1):

I do this as part of the testbench.  However, rather than Assert, I use OSVVM alerts, log, and print.   OSVVM is both at osvvm.org and github.

Rather than Assert, I use AffirmIf for self-checking/result checking.   I use AlertIf for parameter checking.

Step 1 is get OSVVM.  Once you have the code, compile it using the script.  In either Mentor or Aldec, run the script by doing:

```
vlib osvvm
vmap osvvm osvvm
do $PATH_TO_OSVVM/osvvm.do $PATH_TO_OSVVM
```

Use VHDL-2008 and include all of OSVVM in your program by doing:

```
library osvvm;
  context osvvm.OsvvmContext;
```

Then rather than:

```
assert Data /= expected report "..." severity error;
```

Do:

```
AffirmIf(Data = Expected, "...") ;
```

Both assert and AffirmIf/AlertIf print.  However, the advantage to AffirmIf/AlertIf is that internally it keeps a count of the errors and you can get a pass fail at the end of your test by doing:

```
ReportAlerts;
```

The next advantage of OSVVM AffirmIf/AlertIf/Log/Print is that if you want the results in a file, you simply do:

```
TranscriptOpen("./results/Test1.txt");
```

If you want to both print to the screen and a file, also do:

```
SetTranscriptMirror(TRUE);
```

That ought get you started.   I will leave the rest to the user guides.  Start by looking at both the AlertLog package user guide and the transcript package user guide.

Comment: Can you expand on how [OSVVM](http://osvvm.org) can be used with the OP's constraint that he can't modify the Device Under Test? It's not clear from OSVVM's list of capabilities, the [documentation](https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM/tree/master/doc) nor are there posts with applicable titles readily apparent in the [OSVVM forum](http://osvvm.org/forums/forum/os-vvm).

Comment: @user1155120 Where are his assert statements?   In the testbench or RTL code.  Not clear in the post.  Since they are usuall in the testbench that is what I guessed.   OTOH, lets assume I am wrong.   Perhaps the lesser of all evils will be to swap out the asserts in RTL for OSVVM Alert/Log so prints can be redirected.   In the end is there another VHDL solution?   VUNIT is python that runs in the simulator.   The stuff that would be checking the asserts in VUNIT is post processing, hence, does not meet the OP original question either.   Hence, choices have to be made.

Comment: If the assertion were in the testbench the assertion condition could be evaluated again or the assertion made in a process allowing further sequential statements. The model for not doing so is when 'the DUT debug output is an ASSERT/REPORT message to the console' from a DUT assertion and the VHDL revision is less than -2008 where external names aren't available.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but the asserts are generated by the DUT, and cannot be changed.  I think this rules out OSVVM, which I do use, along with Vunit.

Comment: I'm using VHDL 2008, and did wonder about external names, but I'm not sure that it helps.  the requirement is to check the ASSERT output message (string compare).  (Don't ask why, beyond my pay grade, sadly....)